# SSRS Invalid file name. The file name you specified could not be used

Tags: reporting-services

UPDATE:  Dev environment is SSRS2013; prod is 2014.

We are using SSRS 2014 against SharePoint lists.  I have one simple report that uses one list with no problem.  The other one uses 4 lists.  When I run it in our test environment, I have no problem.  I copied the .rdl to the production environment, changed the data source to the right environment but I get an error when I run here: 
[image]

I have tried executing the query for each of the datasets and they run fine from there.  I'm not sure what else to try.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any idea what filename this message is talking about?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea...

Comment: Maybe there are hardcoded paths somewhere and the production environment has different paths?